# Подскажите, в чем может заключаться ошибка при настройке Redux Devtools

Tags: reactjs, redux, google-chrome-devtools

Я следую инструкции, по настройке redux devtools отсюда https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension. При попытке запуска в Инструментах разработчика колонка redux отображается. Но либо, пишет, что Store не найден, либо показывает, Store и функции которые загружены там по умолчанию.
Вот мой код:

./configureStore/index.js

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/index';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';


const initialState = {
  photos: []
}

export default function configureStore() {

  const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

  const enhancers = composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware));

  const store = createStore(rootReducer,initialState,enhancers);

  return store
}
```

and ./containers/Root.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import configureStore from '../configureStore/index.js';
import AsyncApp from './AsyncApp.js'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const store = configureStore();

export default class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AsyncApp />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

and index.js

```
import 'babel-polyfill'

import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import Root from './containers/Root.js'

render(<Root />, document.querySelector('.fixed-container'));
```

this is my reducer.

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import {
  UPLOAD_PHOTOS_REQUEST,
  UPLOAD_PHOTOS_SUCCES,
  UPLOAD_PHOTOS_FAIL
} from '../actions/index.js'

const initialState = {
  isFetching: false,
  error: false,
  photos: []
}

function photos(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPLOAD_PHOTOS_REQUEST:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: true,
        error: false
      })

    case UPLOAD_PHOTOS_SUCCES:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: false,
        error: false,
        payload: action.payload,
        recievedAt: action.receivedAt
      })

    case UPLOAD_PHOTOS_FAIL:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: false,
        error: true,
        payload: action.payload,
      })

    default:
      return {
        ...state,
        photos: state.photos
      }
  }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  photos
})

export default rootReducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

На первый взгляд ваш пример кода должен быть рабочий. Попробуйте использовать `composeWithDevTools`:

```
...
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

...

const enhancers = composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware));

const store = createStore(rootReducer,initialState,enhancers);
```

Либо в вашем коде проверьте существует ли `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__` в configureStore() с помощью `console.log()`.

Answer (score 0):

Все дело было в том, что в настройках в Хроме я не поставил "Разрешить открывать локальные файлы по ссылкам".